# How to update variable from inside a function?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I want to change the value of RowIndex from _getAttendence**

```
class Attendence extends StatefulWidget {
  const Attendence({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Attendence> createState() => _AttendenceState();
}

class _AttendenceState extends State<Attendence> {
  String RowIndex = "0";
Widget build(BuildContext context){...}
 _getAttendence(String KEY, String RowIndex) async {
          RowIndex = "50";
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `RowIndex` variable is an *instance* variable, not a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

RowIndex is not global, it's class wide, it's nested in your State object, if you want to make it global, put it outside the class tag, you could do this

```
    @override
    State<Attendence> createState() => _AttendenceState();
  }

    class _AttendenceState extends State<Attendence> {
  String RowIndex = "0";

  _getAttendence(String KEY, String RowIndex) async {
    for (var q in (aList as List)) {
      AttendenceList innerAttendence = AttendenceList(
          q["RowIndex"],
          q["Id"],
          q["InText"],
          q["OutText"],
          q["InDate"],
          q["Duration"],
          q["DateBGColorHEX"],
          q["InColorHEX"],
          q["OutColorHEX"],
          q["DurationColorHEX"]);
      FetchList.add(innerAttendence);
    }
    setState(() {
      RowIndex = FetchList[FetchList.length - 1].RowIndex.toString();
    });
  }
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
      _getAttendence(KEY!, RowIndex);
    }
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry i uploaded the updated code. nevertheless i still want to update it's value, how should i do that.

Comment: if it's not being used to build UI, then you can just do what you're doing, by calling RowIndex = "50"; but if you're using it to update UI, then you'll have to call setState(), which you can't call unless you're in a state object, so you'll have to link your function to your _AttendenceState();

Comment: even after calling setState not working. setState(() {
      RowIndex = FetchList[FetchList.length - 1].RowIndex.toString();
    });

Comment: what do you mean by not working

Comment: the value isn't getting updated after calling setState()

Comment: where are you calling the change? is it in your _getAttendence method

Comment: yes i'm calling it in _getAttendence

Comment: _getAttendence(String KEY, String RowIndex) async {
    for (var q in (aList as List)) {
      AttendenceList innerAttendence = AttendenceList(
          q["RowIndex"],
          q["Id"],
          q["InText"],
          q["OutText"],
          q["InDate"],
          q["Duration"],
          q["DateBGColorHEX"],
          q["InColorHEX"],
          q["OutColorHEX"],
          q["DurationColorHEX"]);
      FetchList.add(innerAttendence);
    }
    setState(() {
      RowIndex = FetchList[FetchList.length - 1].RowIndex.toString();
    });
  }

Comment: after doing RowIndex = "50"; right below it, add this print(RowIndex); and look in your console when you run the code, to see if the value is the same, then tell me the output

Comment: first off, you shouldn't be calling setState in that method, it wouldn't work, it has no relationship with your state object, it will even throw an error

Comment: showing updated value

Comment: but the real ain't updating.

Comment: where do you call _getAttendence, is it in a future builder or on Button tap

Comment: if it's inside of the _AttendenceState() then please update your question and send the code inside the attendance state

Comment: I call it when an event is triggered.(controller.position.maxScrollExtent) in initState

Comment: then don't make _getAttendence a topLevel function, put it inside your class, before initState, put it there, then you can setState(() { RowIndex = ....}); besides, if you need your UI to update repeatedly from that code, iniState isn't a good place to call it, because initState is called only once

Comment: if (controller.position.maxScrollExtent == controller.offset) {
        _getAttendence(KEY!, RowIndex);
      }. it's repeatedly listening to the event and is working.

Comment: okay, if you're listening, then no problem, I thought you were just calling the method like that and expecting it to update repeatedly, ye, then put the _getAttendence() inside your _AttendenceState() and you can setState(() {RowIndex .....})

Comment: i'll update my answer so that i can write more code in there for you to understand

Answer (score 0):

First option is to create a global variable inside the class like this:

```
// 'a' can also be placed here :)
class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyPage> createState() => _MyPageState();
}

// this is a global variable. It has no colors. (see image)
double a = 20.0;
/*
  now, wherever you import the file containing the class 'MyPage',
  you can use this variable!
 */

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  
  // this is a local variable. It has a purple color. (see image)
  double b = 10.0;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

[image: picture showing the colors]

Second option is to create a dart file, let's call it globals.dart. Then, in this file define your variables, `double a = 10.0;` And then in your other dart files you can either import it as before and use the variables or you can use this: in your other files use: `import: 'globals.dart' as globals;` and then in your file you can use: `globals.a = 20.0;` inside a **setState(()=>{});**. Don't forget to **setState** above as well :)